# GridView vs ListView

Tags: android, gridview

ALL,

I am trying to make a following layout:

```
abc   <Edit_text>
def   <Edit_text>
```

where abc and def are just text labels for the 2 EditText views.

I decided to try the GridView for that, but apparently it is not possible. I am always getting the following layout:

```
abc             def
<Edit_text>     <Edit_text>
```

Should I change it to become a ListView or it can be done with a GridView?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/shipping_address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shipping_address_accept"
        android:text="@string/shipping_address_accept_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/android:TextAppearance.Large"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

line.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shipping_info_line_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/android:TextAppearance.Large"
    />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/shipping_info_line_value"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

[/EDIT]

Thank you.

Comment: try aligning your layout in the way you want. because i have always used GridView for this purpose, and it always worked the way i wanted :)

Comment: Have you tried table layout ?

Comment: @deepdroid, it's too much typing ;-)

Comment: i see :-) I think I wasted my answer below then..

Comment: @Zeeshan, could you post an example here. I can't make it to work properly. Also can this be used as the secondary view (meaning the inner view for some layout)?

Comment: @deepdroid, Yes, this is exactly why I want to skip ListView. Less typing, less error prone

Comment: @Zeeshan, I updated the post with my layouts. Will you be able to spot what's wrong? I guess I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table layout for this,

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abc" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:hint="Enter text"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="def" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text2
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:hint="Enter text"/>
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```